# Sefer Yismach Yisroel digitized

Tags: history, chasidut-hasidism

Does anyone know where I can find a pdf or digital version of a modern print of the Sefer Yismach Yisroel (Aleksander Rebbe)?

I have tried the version on HebrewBooks, but it doesn't seem to match up with my own version at home.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome dave! In order to clarify your question, can you please 1) indicate the URL for the version of the sefer you found on hebrewbooks.com and 2) attach an image of the version of this sefer you have at home?  In this way someone who answers your question will have a better target to shoot at.

Comment: I assume this is the one you found: https://hebrewbooks.org/48065

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Dave and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @shmosel thanks! That actually wasn’t the one I found. Do you know where I can find the rest of it?

Comment: Title: ישמח ישראל, Author: דנציגר

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @shmosel for helping me out.

Part 1: https://hebrewbooks.org/48065

Part 2: https://hebrewbooks.org/59004